Flutter getting minimum supported 7.3.1 error
When i try to make an apk of my application i get this error:
> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
   > Kotlin Gradle Plugin <-> Android Gradle Plugin compatibility issue:
     The applied Android Gradle Plugin version (7.3.0) is lower than the minimum supported 7.3.1.

     Please update the Android Gradle Plugin version to at least 7.3.1.

after getting this error i try to change
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false

to
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false

and running this commands:
flutter clean
./gradlew clean

i get this error:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

could you please help me how can i resolve this problem?

Did you try using the AGP assistant for this?

Glad to hear it helped. Consider posting it as an answer for other people struggling with the same issue.
